# Numpy not converting to new version

Tags: numpy

I just installed Numpy 1.7.1 on Ubuntu by downloading the `tar.gz` file from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.1rc1/). I did `tar zxvf` on the tar file, then `python setup.py build` and `sudo python setup.py install`.

But my Numpy is still the old version (1.3.0). (I checked by running Python and asks for `numpy.version.version`.) Why is that?

Comment: Do you have a Numpy package from the Ubuntu repository installed as well?

Comment: Yes, I suppose my old one is version 1.3.0 (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: Are you sure the python you called from sudo is the same python that you ran afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a little bit about where your packages are and make sure they're built in the right place by using:

```
which python
```

or

```
file `which python`
```

(those are backticks) on the command line, and this will tell you where your python installation is.

Then, launch `python` (or `ipython`) and run

```
import numpy
numpy.__file__
```

If you've installed any packages that do work, import and look at their file locations too.  You'll probably notice that `numpy.__file__` is not in the same location as where you just installed your new numpy package.  Be sure that these match up, or add the location where you installed the new numpy to `PYTHONPATH`.